# Retain rows with the top score within a range of a column start

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, filter

I would like to retain the row with the highest "score" value within 3 places of the start value column. I have a dataframe like the one below:

```
data = {'id':['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5', 'id6'],
       'start':[1,12,11,2,20,3],
       'score':[3,1,8,2,5,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'start',  'score'])
df = df.sort_values(by='start')
```

Desired output:

```
data = {'id':['id3', 'id5', 'id6'],
       'start':[11,20,3],
       'score':[8,5,9]}
output = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'start',  'score'])
output = output.sort_values(by='start')
```

Because id1, id4, & id6 have a start value plus or minus 3, we retain the row with the highest score (id6). The same principal holds for id2 & id3 with id3 being retained. id5 is unique and should be retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this? -

```
bin = range(df['start'].min(), df['start'].max()+3, 3)
cut = pd.cut(df['start'], bins=bin, include_lowest= True)
def test(x):
    return x.sort_values('score').tail(1)
df = df.groupby(cut).apply(test).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, we need to check if the values in `start` and consecutive and if they do, they belong to the same group.
And form this group, we want to filter the rows where the `score` is `max`.
This is how I would do it:

```
cnt = 0
def group(x, y):
    global cnt
    if (x - y) > 1:
        cnt += 1
    return cnt

df['start_2'] = df['start'].shift(1).fillna(1)
df['group'] = df[['start', 'start_2']].apply(lambda x: group(x.start, x.start_2), axis=1)
df = df[df.groupby(['group'])['score'].transform(max) == df['score']]
df.drop(columns=['start_2'], inplace=True)
df
```

So what's happening here:

1. I create a column using the `start` column and shift all values in the downward direction.
2. Next I look at the difference between the two. If the difference is `1`, they belong to the same group, else create a new group using by incrementing the counter. This will give me a new column with the groups.
3. Using this, group by and filter where the `score` is max.